# Transaction isolation READ_COMMITTED losing update

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions, isolation-level

I made sample project with Spring Boot to test isolation levels of transactions. PostgreSQL used as RDBMS, but I guess it's not that important.

### Case

First transaction selects data, changes it and sleeps. While it sleeping, second transaction starts. It selects the same row, makes changes and commits. After that first transaction wakes up and commits it's changes.

### Issue

Is it okay that changes of second transaction are totally lost with `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level on first transaction? Using `REPEATABLE_READ` or `SERIALIZABLE` levels that doesn't happen, and the exception raised when first transaction is trying to commit.

I used minimum Spring Boot project (spring-boot-starter-data-jpa).

Some code:

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public Product firstTransaction(Integer id) {
    Product p = repository.findOne(id);
    p.setName(p.getName() + "+first");
    // Waiting secondTransaction to finish
    try {Thread.sleep(2000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return p;
}

@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public Product secondTransaction(Integer id) {
    try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    Product p = repository.findOne(id);
    p.setName(p.getName() + "+second");
    return p;
}
```

Test

```
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    Future<Product> firstFuture = pool.submit(() -> service.firstTransaction(productId));
    Future<Product> secondFuture = pool.submit(() -> service.secondTransaction(productId));
    try {
        Product firstProduct = firstFuture.get();
        Product secondProduct = secondFuture.get();
        Product productFromRepo = repository.findOne(productId);

        assertEquals("base+first", firstProduct.getName());
        assertEquals("base+second", secondProduct.getName());
        assertEquals(productFromRepo.getName(), firstProduct.getName());
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are handling the transactions correctly? If you change a row and then have the transaction waiting, the row will be locked (there is an entry in pg_locks), and the second transaction should not be able to update AND commit the change. The second transaction will wait until the first one commits.

Comment: Please show the *actual SQL that gets run*. A pile of Java code does not help much. A great deal depends on how the tool/framework you're using handles all this - if it does any caching, etc.